# radio button onclick event does not work

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to get onclick event in html radio buttons to call a function in JavaScript program.

When I use button, it works:

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clickedButton1()">Button1</button>
...
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (in index.js):

```
function clickedButton1 () {
    console.log("clickedButton1")
}
```

But when I use radio button, the onclick does not call the function:

HTML5 (in the same file above):

```
<section id="radioButtons">
    <form action="" method="post" name="radioButtons" id="radioButtons">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" onclick="test()"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" onclick="test()"> No
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Javascript (in index.js):

```
function test () {
    console.log ("test")
}
```

What's wrong with my code?
Any help?

Comment: onclick="test" to onclick="test()"

Comment: I forgot to write parentheses `onclick="test()" `. But even if I add them, it does not work...

Comment: I edited my mistakes above.

Comment: how you have checked console.log() ? use alert("test")

Comment: Using 'JavaScript console' in Chrome. (Is this appropriate answer to your question?)

Comment: I have tried your code it is working fine.

Comment: Does it work if you put your two js functions in a `<script>` tag at the end of your html, before the closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: @Alimon Really? Well... I have no idea how it could be...

Comment: @MichaelP. The first one `clickedButton1()` does work, but second one `test()` does not work. Even, I tried `onclicked="clickedButton1()"` in the radio button section, but it does not work at all.

Comment: `onclicked` would not help for sure. As @Alimon, your code works for me. For debugging purpose, you can try declaring `window.test = function() { ...}` instead of `function test() { .. }`

Comment: See in jsfiddle everything is working fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/pitocms/ma2qm8a8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call `test` function. So this `onclick="test"` should become

```
onclick="test()"
```

It's not enough to just reference function, you need to invoke it with `()` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses. Put `onclick="test()"` instead

Answer (score 0):

Add semicolon at the end of line
console.log("test");

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript function can be invoked without being called. Please see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript is loading before your html ready, you can solve this problem by using your code in body teg or you can use window.onload in your index.js file.Try bellow code I think it will work.

```
function test()
{
    alert("Hi");
}


window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("radio1").onclick = test;
};
```